# How to do Iscsi deep discovery?

Tags: powershell, storage-area-network, iscsi, mpio

In our storage array we change the discovery IP. Once the discovery IP is changed, the Multipath connection has to be rebalanced (It should make connection again with new discovery ip). But it is not rebalanced. We had to do Rescan disk and Iscsi deep discovery.

We found diskpart command to rescan disk

> (rescan | diskpart)

but we could not find a way to do Iscsi deep discovery. How to do Iscsi deep discovery? Is there any powershell cmdlet to do it?

Comment: Update-IscsiTarget does deep discovery.

Answer (score 4):

Since iSCSI discovery IP has changed, you need to manually add a new Discovery portal to the MS iSCSI Initiator by using PowerShell or iscsicpl GUI. Here is the topic on how to add a new Discovery portal: (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/san/2012/07/31/managing-iscsi-initiator-connections-with-windows-powershell-on-windows-server-2012/)